# Removing solidifier mod on a certain part of a mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Just a quick question, is there any way to remove a solidify mod on a certain part of a mesh whilst keeping the modifier intact on the rest of the mesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a vertex group to your mesh, which lets you apply the modifier to a specific set of verticies alone.

See [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html) for more information on the solidify modifier, and [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html#creating-vertex-groups) for information on creating vertex groups.

Comment: No problem. -comment length minimums wat?